# App crash on HttpLoggingInterceptor

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I've created project with Retrofit 2, okhttp and okhttp:logging-interceptor.

```
private static APIInterface apiInterface;
private static RestClient restClient;
private static HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor;

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .header("X-Parse-Application-Id", Constants.PARSE_APP_ID)
                    .header("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", Constants.PARSE_REST_API)
                    .method(original.method(), original.body());

            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(); // got crash here
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    okHttpClient.interceptors().add(interceptor);
```

Here is my trace:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/squareup/okhttp/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor
   at com.rocker.rest.RestClient.setupRestClient(RestClient.java:62)
   at com.rocker.rest.RestClient.<clinit>(RestClient.java:39)
   at com.rocker.fragment.HistoryFragment.onCreateView(HistoryFragment.java:38)
```

I'm not using okio by squareup!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you read this?
https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses

> Retrofit 2 completely relies on OkHttp for any network operation.
>   Since OkHttp is a peer dependency of Retrofit 2, you won’t need to add
>   an additional dependency once Retrofit 2 is released as a stable
>   release.
>
> OkHttp 2.6.0 ships with a logging interceptor as an internal
>   dependency and you can directly use it for your Retrofit client.
>   Retrofit 2.0.0-beta2 still uses OkHttp 2.5.0. Future releases will
>   bump the dependency to higher OkHttp versions. That’s why you need to
>   manually import the logging interceptor. Add the following line to
>   your gradle imports within your build.gradle file to fetch the logging
>   interceptor dependency.
>
> compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'

Comment: the problem was with version of OkHttp, after downgrade on 2.5.0 works fine

Comment: Pls see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/39601180/1145905 if it be of help