# No class found exception com.squareup.okhttp.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

Even after adding the dependencies and importing the class I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.okhttp.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.

Can anyone please help?

Gradle Build file

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xyz"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
 }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Android Studio or eclipse? If Android Studio, are you using Gradle? If yes, can you add the Gradle file to your question?

Comment: @cricket_007 have added the build file

Comment: Are you able to successfully use Gradle build and check that all the dependencies are downloaded?

Comment: How to know that it is downloading the dependencies or not, sorry I am new to android. @cricket_007

Comment: That's fine. In one of the side panels of Android Studio, there should be a Gradle button with a green icon. From there, there should be options for like clean and installDependencies and build. Then in another pane (maybe the one on the left where your files are), there might be a collapsed section for referenced libraries.

Comment: This is helps me [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649121/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-okhttp3-okhttpclientbuilder/36661967#36661967](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649121/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-okhttp3-okhttpclientbuilder/36661967#36661967)

Answer (score 17):

In my case, I found that the versions of the okhttp3 and okhttp3:logging-interceptor dependencies needed to exactly match. So for example:

```
...
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Could be a compatibility problem with retrofit.

Try with :

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.5.0'
```

This post could be help

[App crash on HttpLoggingInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316028/app-crash-on-httplogginginterceptor)

Answer (score -1):

Also it can be connected with **`multidex true`** option in your **`build.gradle`** (yes, seems like some devices have problems with multidex apps (read, **Samsung**))

If this is your case, switch this flag off and rebuild your project. Consider using

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
```

to reduce your apk size. If it is still too large, that's really weird and bad news, but there are some [techniques to put your apk on diet](https://medium.com/google-developers/smallerapk-part-1-anatomy-of-an-apk-da83c25e7003#.ttcsr2lin).