# Cannot see a class inside a package that was added as a dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, okhttp

I cannot see what is wrong with this build files:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}
plugins {
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.12"
    id "me.tatarka.retrolambda" version "3.7.0"

}
allprojects {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    ext {
        supportVersion = "26.1.0"
        daggerVersion = "2.12"
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

apply from: "./dependencies.gradle"
```

dependencies.gradle:

```
ext {
minSdkVersion = 19
compileSdkVersion = 26
buildToolsVersion = "26.0.1"

supportVersion = "26.1.0"


retrofitVersion = "2.3.0"
daggerVersion = "2.12"
picassoVersion = "2.5.2"
rxJava = "2.1.5"
rxAndroid = "2.0.1"
butterKnifeVersion = "8.8.1"
gsonVersion = "2.8.2"
firebaseVersion = "11.4.2"
googleServicesVersion = "11.4.2"

constraintLayoutVersion = "1.0.2"

firebaseUIVersion = "3.0.0"

okHttpVersion = "3.9.0"

lib_android = [
        supportAppCompat      : "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportVersion}",
        supportCoreUi         : "com.android.support:support-core-ui:${supportVersion}",
        supportGridLayout     : "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${supportVersion}",
        supportPalette        : "com.android.support:palette-v7:${supportVersion}",
        supportVerctorDrawable: "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:${supportVersion}",
        supportAnnotations    : "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportVersion}",
        supportCardView       : "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportVersion}",

        constraintLayout      : "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:${constraintLayoutVersion}",

        dagger                : "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}",
        picasso               : "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:${picassoVersion}",

        rxJava                : "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${rxJava}",
        rxAndroid             : "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:${rxAndroid}",

        butterknife           : "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${butterKnifeVersion}"


]


apt_android = [
        butterKnifeCompiler: "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${butterKnifeVersion}",
        daggerCompiler     : "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
]


lib_database = [
        supportAppCompat: "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportVersion}",
        firebaseCore    : "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${firebaseVersion}",
        firebaseDatabase: "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:${firebaseVersion}",
        firebaseAuth    : "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:${firebaseVersion}",
        firebaseUiAuth  : "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:${firebaseUIVersion}"
]
lib_java = [
        retrofit         : "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofitVersion}",
        retrofitConverter: "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofitVersion}",
        retrofitAdapter  : "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:${retrofitVersion}",

        okHttp           : "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${okHttpVersion}",
        okHttpLogging    : "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${okHttpVersion}",

        rxJava           : "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${rxJava}",
        dagger           : "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}",

        gson             : "com.google.code.gson:gson:${gsonVersion}"


]


apt_java = [
        daggerCompiler: "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
]
test_common = [
        junit       : "junit:junit:4.12",
        hamcrestCore: "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3"
]
```

}

java-library module:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    def ext = rootProject.ext

    ext.lib_java.each {
        k, v -> compile v
    }

    ext.apt_java.each {
        k, v -> apt v
    }
    ext.test_common.each {
        k, v -> testCompile v
    }

}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

Everything was fine with this build script so far, but now I added this dependency:

```
okHttpLogging    : "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${okHttpVersion}",
```

Which has only [one class](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) HttpLoggingInterceptor. But even though the build works without problems, I cannot see that class in my project. I did a clean/rebuild project and tried many times but nothing helps.

---- EDIT ----

I create a new android project and add a java module and add `logging-interceptor` there, and everything works fine.

the problem could be some incompatibility of other dependencies with the dependency that I added? for example, internally retrofit imports OkHttp (not logging-interceptor) as well.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it was some issues with Retrofit Okhttp version. I solved it downgrading its version:

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.5.0'

[No class found exception com.squareup.okhttp.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438893/no-class-found-exception-com-squareup-okhttp-logging-httplogginginterceptor/39601180#39601180)